# Android : Presenting transparent activity causes crash

Tags: android, android-activity, transparent

Basically, I have an app with two Activities.

**#1 - MainActivity**
This has a solid black background and a button.
When the button is pressed TransparentActivity should be presented.

**#2 - TransparentActivity**
I want this to be transparent (so the phones normal UI can be seen through).

I've tried using the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_trick);
}
```

But it causes the app to crash with an NullPointerException.

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android

I hope this helps


Regards

Comment: @Androidme I just tried that and it causes an crash too.

Comment: If I apply the Theme to MainActivity it gets transparent, but if I set the TransparentActivity's theme to be transparent it crashes.

Comment: From a user called Max - AppCompatActivity hasn't the Theme_Translucent(maybe the Theme_Translucent is null),you should create your own style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try1:**

Make `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` call after `setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);`. So do as:

```
setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

**Try 2:**

If that doesn't work, I find the following way easiest to make my activity transparent:

```
<activity android:name=".your.activity.declaration.here" 
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
```

Basically add `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"` to your activity declaration in manifest. I can see that you are trying to do a similar thing programatically but by specifying it in manifest never crashed for me. If it does, then there might be other reasons.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions; Try 1 did the same and Try 2 simply made the app unresponsive when tapping the button.

I have a lot of iOS experience but is very new to Android Development.

Comment: For 1) Can you post the stacktrace/log please? 
For 2) By unresponsive you mean that nothing happen when you click the button or it hangs?

Comment: Update:
2) almost works - the second activity is shown with a transparent background. But it is on top of the first.

The goal is to see the 'home screen' of the Android Phone through the TransparentActivity (having MainActivity being 100% invisible so to speak)

Comment: Is your second `TransparentActivity` are you using `android:width="match_parent` and `android:height="match_parent"` in the outermost layout of the layout xml file? If yes change them to `wrap_content`. This will only cover the necessary space. Rest of the `MainActivity` will be visible then.

Comment: I want to do the opposite :) Making the TransparentActivity transparent and MainActivity should not be seen at all.

So the user will see the content of TransparentActivity and under that the normal Android UI.

Comment: You must be using intents to start the second activity. So before you start the `TransparentActivity` from the `MainActivity`, call `MainActivity.finish()`( after calling `startActivity(..)` function). Your MainActivity will end and a new activity will start which will be transparent.

Comment: Great it works, apart from the fact I can't go back to the MainActivity since I've finished it?

Comment: It depends when do you want to go back to the `MainActivity`. If you want to go to the main activity when you press the `back` button, then override the `onBackPressed` function from inside `Activity` and again start the `MainActivity` using intent. Otherwise you can again start it from any button press etc.  Glad it helped. Feel free to upvote/accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

**AppCompatActivity** hasn't the `Theme_Translucent(maybe the Theme_Translucent is null)`,you should create your own style.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question it is more of a comment, when you have hit 50 reputation you can [comment everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) for now i have added the comment for you